# Visual Studio won't run .NET 4 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I changed the target framework of a WPF application to use .NET 4 and now Visual Studio refuses to run it when I press F5. There are no errors, nothing in the build window, it just does nothing.

If I run it manually outside Visual Studio, it runs. If I change it back to .NET 3.5, it runs.

I tried running with logging enabled, but the log didn't have anything debugging-related. But [here it is anyway](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/313489/vslog/ActivityLog.xml). Anything else I should try?

Comment: Did you change the target framework to ".NET Framework 4" or ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"?

Comment: Do you see anything in the Output window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system restart fixed it. Weird.